# Where are Wine files stored in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wine

I just used Wine to install a program in the "Program Files (x86)" folder. I would like to use wine to be able to run this program instead of having to run the installer every time I want to use it. Where does Wine keep its program files folder? Or else, how can I use Wine to run programs in this folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in  `/home/Username/.wine/Drive_C`.

You have to check 'Show hidden files' in your file manager to see `.wine` directory.